# maven project using rest controller and gave a basic request and gives 404. url : http://localhost:8080/Spring4MVCHelloWorldRestServiceDemo/testrest

Tags: spring, rest, controller, http-status-code-404

I created a maven project using rest controller and gave a basic request but it is not hitting the method and gives 404.i am new to the rest controller. So it would be great if someone try to narrow down the issue.
the url : http://localhost:8080/Spring4MVCHelloWorldRestServiceDemo/testrest

**HelloController**

```
    package com.fis.controller;

    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

    @RestController
    public class HelloController {

        @RequestMapping(value="/testrest", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String welcome() {//Welcome page, non-rest
            System.out.println("Test++++++++++++++");
            return "Welcome to RestTemplate Example.";
        }

    /*    @RequestMapping("/hello/{player}")
        public Message message(@PathVariable String player) {//REST Endpoint.

            Message msg = new Message(player, "Hello " + player);
            return msg;
       }*/
    }
```

**HelloInitialization**

```
    package com.fis.configuration;

    import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

    public class HelloInitialization extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

        @Override
        protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
            return new Class[] { HelloConfiguration.class };
        }

        @Override
        protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected String[] getServletMappings() {
            return new String[] { "/" };
        }

    }
```

**HelloConfiguration**

```
    package com.fis.configuration;

    import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

    @Configuration
    @EnableWebMvc
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.fis.controller"})
    public class HelloConfiguration {


    }
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.websystique.springmvc</groupId>
<artifactId>Spring4MVCHelloWorldRestServiceDemo</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<name>Spring4MVCHelloWorldRestServiceDemo Maven Webapp</name>

<properties>
    <springframework.version>4.3.0.RELEASE</springframework.version>
    <jackson.library>2.7.5</jackson.library>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.library}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.library}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>


<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
                    <warName>Spring4MVCHelloWorldRestServiceDemo</warName>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

    <finalName>Spring4MVCHelloWorldRestServiceDemo</finalName>
</build>
```

Comment: Add content of your pom.xml also. Are you deploying to Tomcat, or ...?

Comment: Added POM.xml . I am deploying in Jboss